# ace:chart piechart how to add a title within the graph

Tags: primefaces, jqplot, icefaces-3

I am using icefaces 3.2. I want to know how to add a title to the ace:chart piechart , and this title should be shown within the chart area.

Comment: not sure if it will help , but ChartMeta got title attribute , maybe you can set that object to some attribute of the `ace:chart`